# How do I add a PHP code that will always open/create a new text file and write user input once user clicks 'Submit' button

Tags: php, html, file

How do I add a PHP code that will always open/create a new text file and write user input once user clicks 'Submit' button.

This is the html code

```
<form action="save_redirect.php" id="#form" method="post" name="#form">
  <label>Email:</label><br>
  <input id="email" name="email" placeholder='Enter A Valid Email Address' type='text'>
  <br>
  <input id='btn' name="submit" type='submit' value='Submit'>
  <?php
  include "include/redirect.php";
  ?>
</form>
```

This is the php code I already wrote for redirecting.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  // Fetching variable of the form which travels in URL
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $myfile = fopen("text.txt", "w");
  fwrite($myfile, $email);
  fclose($myfile);

  if($email !='') {
    header("Location:https://www.formget.com/app/");
  }
  else {
    ?><span><?php echo "Please fill the email field! This is where you'll receive script files on.";?></span> <?php
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? You can google how to create a text file using PHP in a few seconds. Is the problem how to make sure it's a new file each time? Or how to put the right data into it? Or what? Please explain the exact issue you're facing, and show how you've tried to research and solve the problem already (because I would be astonished if it's a new issue that no-one ever wrote about online before).

Comment: What user input do you want to write? The only input is the email address.

Comment: You can use the `file_put_contents()` function to write something to a file.

Comment: @ADyson Yes, how to make sure it's a new file each time

Comment: @Barmar yes, input is only Email address

Comment: You can use the `uniqid()` function to generate a unique filename.

Comment: @Barmar thanks, you can write that as an answer cos I'm not yet sure how to use uniqid( ). Also I've made edits to the PHP code please check it out to be sure if it's now ok. If not please do correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `uniqid()` to generate a unique filename. And you can use `file_put_contents()` to combine `fopen()/fwrite()/fclose()`.

```
$filename = uniqid() . ".txt";
file_put_contents($filename, $email);
```